# Little gap in a menu although margin and padding 0

Tags: html, css

I've a problem: I want to create a responsive menu but in the mobile mode there is something like `margin-left` and `margin-top` and I don't know how to delete these gaps.
Here's my code:

```css
body{
  font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 100%;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -o-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto; 
}

#main{
  max-width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  background-color:#FF9;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#menu{
  width:20%;
  background-color:#09F;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
}

#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
}

#menu a:hover{
  color: red;
  text-decoration:underline;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #main{
    max-width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    left:0%;
    margin:0px;
  }

  #menu{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background-color:green;
    height: 60px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
  }

  #menu li{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position:relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;

    display: block;
    width:  120px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:red;

  } 
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Does someone know where I made a mistake?

Comment: take of text-align on  #menu element the space is coming from this style

Comment: nope, nothing changed

Comment: li is already block element,why do you want to use float:left here if you want make them bhave like float element

Comment: check this http://codepen.io/sahithiK/pen/ObxVMm ..is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: wasn't sure about it ... thought that this float could create this gaps

Comment: screenshot plz with your indicating problem

Comment: nope, this isn't what I want to do. Scale the browser window below 800px and you'll still see the gaps

Comment: ul takes some default value `margin-left`

Comment: what I want to do is basically to remove the whole green space so that the menu items together have the same size as the browser window. you can see the green space if you scale the browser window below 800px

Comment: @PrasathV you did it, thanks. I've added 
`#menu ul{
 margin:0px;
 padding: 0px;
}`

But why do I have to add it here?

Comment: welcome :)  @DrSheldonTrooper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ul` has default indent value

```
ul{
   margin-left:20px;
  }
```

To avoid this conflict you have to write this code on top of your css

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;// Padding also took some indent. You can use if it was requires
 }
```

or write like this

```
 ul{
    margin-left:0;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You were trying to make the menu as position :absolute and each li as relative and making them as display:block(float:left) ,you need not do that all. Float:left makes element display:block.

Instead of all this, you can consider using display:flex for the layout instead of floats.

Flexbox is responsive too.

check the following snippet

```css
body {
  font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 100%;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -o-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
#main {
  max-width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #FF9;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#menu {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #09F;
  line-height: 20px;
}
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
}
#menu a:hover {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #main {
    max-width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    left: 0%;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  #menu {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  #menu ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  #menu li {
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link href="css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type "text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i understood correctly but maybe this is what you are searching for:

```
#menu ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was searching for, like @PrasathV said in the comments before. Thanks for that.

But why do I have to do this? Does ul uses some default margins?

Comment: the list indentation is to ensure that the markers do not fall off the left edge.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance what you're seeing is the default stylesheet embedded in the browser. You should generally reset your stylesheets by using this at the beginning of your CSS file. This resets all pre-defined paddings/margins etc to 0.

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/*============ END OF RESET =================*/
```

I've a feeling this is related to your problem. It's worth trying it out.

Comment: Nice, i'll try it out. I was using something called "normalizer" before but it seems that he didn't rest this

Answer (score 1):

you could also use flexbox see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f76vdyxe/

```css
body{
    font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 100%;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -o-hyphens: auto;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto; 
}

#main{
    max-width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    background-color:#FF9;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#menu{
    width:20%;
    background-color:#09F;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
}

#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
}

#menu a:hover{
    color: red;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
  }
#main{
    max-width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    left:0%;
    margin:0px;
}

#menu{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background-color:green;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}

#menu li{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position:relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;

    display: block;
    background-color:red;
    
    flex: 1;

} 
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't knew something like Flexbox exist. I'll have to check it out.